# How to correctly wish birthday in terms of age number?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

Suppose I was born in May 12, 1999.

So first doubt is: Is May 12, 1999 will be called my first **birthday**?

Further doubt related to it is:

On May 12, 2020, you'll be 21 years old. So shall I wish the person as

"Happy 21st birthday"

OR

"Happy 22nd birthday *(because 1st **birthday** was (was it?) on May 12, 1999. Including that May 12 came 22 times)*"

OR

PS: Same doubt remains if I replace the word birthday with **anniversary** in above 2 options.

Comment: My [**birthday**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/birthday) can mean the day I was born, but generally it is the *anniversary* of that day. So your 21st birthday is the 21st *anniversary* of your birth, when you are 21 years old.

Comment: May 12 2000 was your _first_ birthday (when you reached the age of one year).

Comment: Is this concept also true for Republic Day, Independence Day like anniversaries?